# 3 unit vectors a b and c

Tags: vectors

a b and c are 3 vectors of unit lengths, every 2 of which are inclined to each other at an angle of arccos 3/5 if a×b =pa+ qb + rc. Then write the value of 55q^2 .

To be honest i dont know how to start. Like they give 3 unknowns and they ask the value of one. Im confused. How to tackle these kinda questions? Pls help.

Comment: aaoaaaha okaaay. thankyou

Comment: @Parcly, I don't follow. If $a=(1,0,0)$, $b=(0,1,0)$, $c=(1,1,1)$, say, then $a\times b$ is not a scalar multiple of $c$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson well but a×b cannot be expressed in linear combination of a and b atleast. They are non coplaner hence linearly independent which suggests p and q got to be 0 right?

Comment: Wrong. $r\ne0$ doesn't imply $p=q=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to see that vectors $a,b,c$ generate a pyramid with an equilateral triangle basis and isosceles faces (see figure below). Let us consider this pyramid as being upside down with its apex at the origin and its basis on plane $z=h$. Moreover, one can take $a, b, c$ such that their projection on the horizontal plane are at angles $0, \dfrac{2 \pi}{3} , \dfrac{-2 \pi}{3}$ with $x$-axis, giving:

$$a=\begin{pmatrix}r\\0\\h \end{pmatrix}, \ \ b=\begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{1}{2}r\\\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r\\h \end{pmatrix},  \ \ c=\begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{1}{2}r\\-\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}r\\h \end{pmatrix}$$

Constraints are

$$\tag{1}\begin{cases}r^2+h^2=1 &\text{(unit norm)}\\h^2-\tfrac12r^2=\tfrac35&\text{(dot product)}\end{cases}$$

Solving system (1) gives :

$$\tag{2}r=\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{15}} \ \text{and} \ h=\tfrac{\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt{15}}.$$

Besides, $a \times b = \begin{pmatrix}-rh\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\-\tfrac{3}{2}rh\\r^2 \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{pmatrix}.$

Now taking into account $a \times  b =pa+ qb + rc$, we can express $p, q, r$, using Cramer's formulas, under the form :

$$\tag{3}p=\dfrac{\det(a\times b, b, c)}{\det(a, b, c)}, \ q=\dfrac{\det(a, a\times b, c)}{\det(a, b, c)}, \ r=\dfrac{\det(a, b, a\times b)}{\det(a, b, c)}$$

Replacing $a,b,c,a \times b$ by their expressions, all computations done, one gets :

$$p=-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{55}}, \ q=-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{55}}, \ r=\dfrac{8}{\sqrt{55}}$$

Thus the answer to the problem is $55q^2=9.$

[image]

Comment: Theres no need of all this. We can simply take dots on both sides with a×c

Comment: See the edit I have done to show that the idea is the same. You say "there is no need of all this" : then how do you compute $(a\times b) . (a\times c)$ ?

Comment: And why do we need to compare these

Comment: Because you just said you have taken dots on both sides of $a x b= p a + q b + r c$ with $a x c$, thus you have to "compute" (not "compare") the value of the following dot product : $(a\times b) . (a\times c)$...

Comment: Oh, we do that by the 2x2 det

Comment: We already know their magnitudes and angles b/w them as given in ques

Comment: I just ended the computation : $q=-\dfrac{\sqrt{55}}{3}$

Comment: The answer should be integral

Comment: All right, I stop there; I thought I had helped...

Comment: Lol yea you did. Your soln gave me the idea. Thanks. Answer is 9 though.

Comment: I have computed again the values of p,q,r and corrected my error. I am now in agreement with value $9$. Besides, I have added a picture.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Answer (score 4):

Recall $u\cdot v=|u|\,|v|\,\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$. So we have $$0=a\cdot a\times b=pa\cdot a+qa\cdot b+ra\cdot c=p+(3/5)q+(3/5)r$$ and similarly $$0=b\cdot a\times b=(3/5)p+q+(3/5)r$$ Also, $|u\times v|=|u|\,|v|\,|\sin\theta|$, so $|a\times b|=3/5$, but $$|a\times b|^2=(pa+qb+rc)\cdot(pa+qb+rc)=p^2+(6/5)pq+(6/5)pr+q^2+(6/5)qr+r^2$$ So, now you have three equations in the three unknowns $p$, $q$, and $r$.

Comment: I find your solution very "natural". I have provided a solution that uses a (rather natural too)  "realization" of $a,b,c$.